# How does a robot protect its own existence

Tags: mythology-of-ai, asimovs-laws, survival

What are the many ways that artificial intelligence robots protect their existence?

Isaac Asimov's "Three Laws of Robotics"

A robot may not injure a human being or, through inaction, allow a human being to come to harm.

A robot must obey orders given it by human beings except where such orders would conflict with the First Law.

A robot must protect its own existence as long as such protection does not conflict with the First or Second Law.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, the scenarios where automata protect their own existence is limited.

In the case of autonomous vehicles, primary goals would certainly be collision avoidance, and other hazards (deep water, cliff faces, etc.)

It's possible that arial drones could have certain automated defense mechanisms specific to airborne threats such a missiles.

Bots might be said to protect their existence by copying themselves onto new systems.